# Why does JavaScript 'hide menu onscroll' not work (perfectly) on Safari-Browser

Tags: javascript, html

works on firefox, chrome, edge.
on safari the menu (navbar) appears on scrooling up, but when scrolling to the top of the page, it hides (floats up beyond window) by itself without any scrolling-down action.
any ideas why?

in javascript.js:

```
var prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
let hideNavbar = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.top = "-64px";
  }
  prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
}

window.onscroll = hideNavbar;
```

in index.html underneath the head:

```
<body>
  <header id="menu">
  ...
  </header>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: If you provided the HTML it would help.

Comment: I guess it could be issued by safari's UX that lets you scroll a bit beyond the top (showing white space) and then jumping back down to the actual rim of the document. Maybe there is a trick to work around that ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting this has to do with Safari's "scroll bounce" at the top and bottom of the document. Perhaps you'd be better off adding a mouse wheel event listener?

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

document.addEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);

function handleScrollUp() {
  console.log("UP");
  menu.style.top = "0";
}

function handleScrollDown() {
  console.log("DOWN");
  menu.style.top = "-100px";
}

function handleScroll(event) {
  if ((event.wheelDelta && event.wheelDelta > 0) || event.deltaY < 0) {
    handleScrollUp();
  } else {
    handleScrollDown();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <p>I AM A MENU: </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That works on safari now. But not on mobile Brave Browser

Answer (score 1):

If your header id="menu" is position: fixed; changing it to position: sticky; worked for me. This eliminated the element disappearing in safari.
Add overflow: auto; if the background disappears.